# How to find the equivalent way in nix to install a package

Tags: nix

I've to install the package build-essential. (because of this error using cargo :

> cargo build ->linker cc not found

)

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I've search in the list of package of nix but I've find it.

How can I install build-essential with nix

Comment: `build-essential` is a debian concept that doesn't translate 1:1 to something in Nixpkgs, but `stdenv` is fairly close. Other than that, in Nix we actually care as much about the input (e.g. `stdenv`) as where it is going. Specifically, we try to keep our global environment clear of build dependencies, because those are better managed at the project level using `nix-shell`, and/or in case of a Nix-packaged package, managed through the `buildInputs` and `nativeBuildInputs` attributes of the package.

Comment: @RobertHensing I've tried nix-env -iA nixos.stdenv_NoCC ;cargo build ->linker `cc` not found (same problem)

Comment: nix-env rollback

Comment: same thing with stdenv_32bit. It fails too

Comment: Why are you installing something named **No** CC when cargo is telling you it can't find `cc`?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've search on google. no cc means that you can't link and you must install the linux package build-essential. Therefore I'm searching the equivalent in nix

Comment: You tried `nix-env -iA nixos.stdenv_NoCC` but "NoCC" in the name probably means it doesn't have a C compiler so I'm still confused why you picked out that particular thing to install, when it has that name.  Why not try `nix-env -iA nixos.stdenv` or even `nix-env -iA nixos.gcc` ?  (The latter works for me.)

Comment: I've search stdenv in nixos /search package / search stdenv .  your command wasn't proposed. I've tried. But now I've install that with your command

Comment: @DavidGrayson it doesn't work either. I still have the same problem (cc)

Comment: What does `nix-shell -p gcc --run 'cc --version'` print for you?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: I think you are missing some output there because I don't see a version number but it does look like the `gcc` package provides a `cc` executable for you, so does that answer your question?

Comment: @David Grayson It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gcc` package in nixpkgs provides `cc` so the solution was to make sure `gcc` is installed in your environment or shell.